# Can an anonymous lambda function be bound to an object to allow the code in the lambda to access the object's members?

Tags: c++

I want to allow a lambda function to access members of an object. There are 2 classes involved here:

**The class I want to access**

```
class D {
public:
  void doIt() {};
};
```

**An initializer class for management**

```
template<typename T>
class I {
public:
    I(std::function<void ()> f) {
      someManager->register(this);
      _func = f;
    }

    void run() {
        T* t = new T();
        auto fn = std::bind(t, _func);
        fn();
    }

private:
    std::function<void ()> _func;
};

static I<D> _init_([]() {
    doIt();
});
```

Then in `someManager` I'd call: `i->run()`. However, the call to `doIt()` is not accepted. What must be changed to make this compile and work?

Comment: you need a `D` instance to call (non-static) methods

Comment: ... you want to call `doIt` on the instance you create in `run`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's the intention.

Comment: And except inside D, just plain `doIt` refers to a free standing function with same name. If you want to get the member function, you need `&D::doIt` (address-of is not optional with member functions).

Comment: Not sure I understand but declare function as `static void doIt() {}` and call it like  `D::doIt();` doesn't solve yout question ?

Answer (score 3):

A working version with fixes:

```
class D {
public:
  void doIt() {};
};

template<typename T>
class I {
public:
    I(std::function<void(D*)> f) {
      _func = f;
    }

    void run() {
        T* t = new T();
        auto fn = std::bind(_func, t);
        fn();
        // Alternatively.
        _func(t);
    }

private:
    std::function<void(D*)> _func;
};

I<D> _init_([](D* p) {
    p->doIt();
});

int main() {
    _init_.run();
}
```

Instead of `std::function<void(D*)>` you can also use `void(*)(D*)` because lambda expression `[](D* p) { p->doIt();}` doesn't capture anything and hence it is convertible to a plain function pointer `void(*)(D*)`.

The code also doesn't need to allocate `D` on the heap, an automatic object would suffice. E.g.:

```
void run() {
    T t;
    _func(&t);
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't need `std::bind` if I used a parameter. And for design reasons I would like to avoid a parameter in the lambda.

Comment: @MikeLischke Yep, you can call it as `_func(t);`, see the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to magic a `D` into scopes without it being referenced in intervening scopes, and failing. Not only is the lambda invalid, but so is `std::bind(t, _func)`.

Unrelatedly, you are also leaking the `D`s you `new`.

You can construct a `std::function<void (T&)>` from a `void(T::*)()` (member with compatible other arguments)

```
template<typename T>
class I {
public:
    I(std::function<void (T&)> f) : _func(f) {
      someManager->register(this);
    }

    void run() {
        T t;
        _func(t);
    }

private:
    std::function<void (T&)> _func;
};

static I<D> _init_(&D::doIt);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an instance of `D` to call `doIt`, so you must pass it to the lamdba somehow:

```
#include <functional>

class D {
public:
  void doIt() {};
};



template<typename T>
class I {
public:
    I(std::function<void (T&)> f) {
      //someManager->register(this);
      _func = f;
    }

    void run() {
        T* t = new T();
        _func(*t);
    }

private:
    std::function<void (T&)> _func;
};

static I<D> _init_([](D& d) {
    d.doIt();
});
```

This should work, however, note that `std::function` is quite a beast. It encapsulates all kinds of callables. So when you know that you only need member functions then it might be better to store a member function pointer as member.

And note that your `run` leaks the `new`ed object. I guess that is just for the example, so I didnt fix it here.

Comment: Either bind and call without parameter or call original function directly with; that mixture is invalid, though.

Comment: Hm, suppose you'll stick with. People tend never to come back once they downvoted, even if the answer gets fixed – especially those incapable to leave a comment on their own...

Comment: @Aconcagua I dont care that much about the lost rep, but I do care about mistakes and errors in my posts ;)